# List folders with Variable list?

Tags: powershell

I have a variable ($a) containing the list of all computer names in our domain.
How can I get a certain location on all of those computers?
My idea was to do something like

```
Get-Childitem -Path \\$a\c$\FooBar
```

But this doesn't work. Any ideas or pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `$a` is a list `(Array)` of computers, you can't pass it directly to `Get-ChildItem`

You need to iterate the list and execute the `Get-ChildItem` on one computer each time, like this:

```
foreach ($computer in $a)
{
    Get-Childitem -Path \\$computer\c$\FooBar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or create an array of full paths from the $a aray first:

```
$b = $a | ForEach-Object { '\\{0}\c$\FooBar' -f $_ }
Get-ChildItem -Path $b
```